# Split View App, display PDF's in the Detail View, PDF's are local storage

Tags: ios, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller

I have a Split View App that I am building, using a plist for my Array, and using a UIWebView to display content in the DetailViewController. Using the below code to make calls to the URL address in my plist, and the URL Address is displaying a PDF in the DetailViewController through the UIWebView.

DetailViewController.m

```
NSString *mutareURL = [_detailItem description];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:mutareURL];
[_catalog loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]];
```

What I need to do is have all of the PDF's in my resource folder in my project.  I can use an NSArray or plist for the RootViewController (TableView), but I need to have the ability to display the PDF's in the DetailViewController through the UIWebView when a Row is selected in the RootViewController (TableView).  I tried this Code in my DetailViewController.m file, but it is not working.

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"%@" ofType:@"pdf"];
NSURL *targetURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:targetURL];
[_Pdf loadRequest:request];
```

I have an NSLog in my RootViewController.m file with this code, and i do see that the names of the pdf files are showing up in my debugger.  I just do not know how to get them from the RootViewController and pass them into the pathforResourse"@"%@" ofType:@"pdf"]; area.  brochures is an NSArray that has all of the addObject:@"nameofpdfs" that is passing.

RootViewController.m

```
detailViewController.detailItem = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [brochures objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
NSLog(@"Cell created for row: %d", [indexPath row]);
NSLog(@"brochures = %@", detailViewController.detailItem);
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The answer is probably in the last snippet. The first line essentially passes the selected filename from the `RootViewController` to the `DetailViewController` by setting the latter's `detailItem` property.

If you replace

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"%@" ofType:@"pdf"];
```

by

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: self.detailItem ofType:@"pdf"];
```

it should work.

Depending on whether the filenames in the `brochures` array already contain the `@".pdf"` suffix, you might have to leave it out of the message send:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: self.detailItem ofType: nil];
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I did not realize that I could put the self.detailItem in.  I had to use nil for the ofType.